# Violation of PRIMARY Key (Duplicate key) on a table where the PK is Identity?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

So I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Snapshots].[Crashproof](
    [EmoteCountId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SnapshotId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Emote] [nvarchar](42) NOT NULL,
    [EmoteCountTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Count] [decimal](19, 6) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_SnapshotsCrashproof] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EmoteCountId] ASC) ON [PRIMARY],
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SnapshotsCrashproof_Snapshots] FOREIGN KEY ([SnapshotId]) REFERENCES [Snapshots].[Snapshots] ([SnapshotId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SnapshotsCrashproof_EmoteCountTypes] FOREIGN KEY ([EmoteCountTypeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[EmoteCountTypes] ([EmoteCountTypeId])
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

and this code that inserts into it:

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, trans))
{
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Snapshots.Crashproof";
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("SnapshotId", "SnapshotId"));
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("EmoteCountTypeId", "EmoteCountTypeId"));
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("Emote", "Emote"));
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("Count", "Count"));

    using (IDataReader reader = ObjectReader.Create(emoteCountTypesToSnapshot))
    {
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
    }
}
```

it runs fine 99.99% of the time (and the bulk copy is done every minute), however I did have an exception once, it was on the last line (`bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);`):

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint...Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'Snapshots.Crashproof'. The duplicate key value is (247125).

I get it that bulk inserting directly in the final table is not recommended, I will modify my code to bulk insert into a staging table, then insert from there. But is it what caused this exception?

I really don't understand how a duplicate key can occur on an Identity field :|

Comment: Is it possible that there's already data in your destination table, where a record was added manually with EmoteCountId = 247125?  Perhaps a manual insert when IDENTITY_INSERT was turned ON?

Comment: Could the bulk copy be taking more than a minute, so it starts another write before the first one finished?

Comment: @DeanGoodman no, I never insert manually into this table

Comment: @MattWilko no, the bulk operation usually takes less than a second

Comment: Usually, except for the 0.01% of cases??

Comment: does bulkCopy do an implicit commit or explicit commit..? can you issue an explicit commit after to see if it still errors or not..?

Comment: @MattWilko hmm well I can't diagnose that particular case anymore so I can't confirm 100%, but I would not see why that one time it would have taken more than a minute...thanks for raising the possibility though, nothing is impossible I guess, I'll think about it if it happens again

Comment: @MethodMan I did not declare a transaction for the connection of this operation, so it is implicit (that's what you mean?). I will try to make an explicit commit with `var trans = connection.BeginTransaction()` and `trans.Commit()`, maybe it will help

Comment: I have no idea about the reason but truncate may be useful for you. Can you truncate table before bulk insert ?

Comment: try running profiler / see what the database is seeing...

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use an ETL product to do these kinds of tasks. They organize everything for you and just do such a cleaner job. Messing around with bulk copys and stored procedures and making staging tables (which i did for years) is just so ugly to me now.

I've been using Pentaho Kettle for the last few years and have totally fallen in love with it. This task would take me mere minutes, or maybe under a minute, to implement, and does all the heavy lifting of sanely moving/transforming data from place to place in big heaps.

I know it's not a direct answer to your question but it's the immediate thing I would suggest if someone came to me at work with this question.

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be a race condition on the bulk copy.

If I understand correctly, you are running a bulk copy every minute, and yes, most of the time it will work correctly but depending on the batch size you are trying to insert it will take longer than a minute.

So, assuming that. It can happen to collapse one bulk copy to another trying to insert at the same time records with the same key leading to a Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint.